# Catia V6 record macro

Tags: macros, catia

How can I record a macro in Catia V6? If I use the start recording function from tools, whatever I do the macro is empty (only contains Sub CATMain() End Sub).

Answer (score 0):

Should work. Which release of CATIA v6? What OS? Catvba or something else?

Comment: ENOVIA V6R2013x.HF73, Windows 7 Enterprise. I used built in macro recorder with both catscript and ms vbscript but the output is the same.

Comment: RTR? :-) . Recording is not the best solution, many, many things are not recorded or what is recorded is irrelevant. You have to start study the documentation.

Comment: Yes RTR :)  I know it's not the best solution, but it helps me to understand how catia is recognizing some methods/functions and then I try to figure out how to access them in vba, since I don't have programming experience :)

Comment: V6 is not V5, definetly. You can check several chm files in your ENOVIA installation folder, especially DSYAutomation.chm . Be aware that in your case ENOVIA is highly customized, with several things which cannot be found in other companies installation.

Comment: Yes, i know that it's customized but i try in parallel on normal version and it works (V5 only). I wanted to use recording in V6 to make a comparison, i know about DSYAutomation.chm but firstly i want to finish with a macro for V5 and then I'll try to figure out how to move it to V6 :)

Comment: If you post your code for v5 here, maybe we can help you with "migration"... or maybe you can find what I already done in RTR.

Comment: Well, it's not completed yet. How can i find you in RTR? :)

Comment: Search on Google for "ferdo CATIA" :-)